# Thymeleaf "foreach" without root element

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I need somethink like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- th:each="value : ${values}" -->
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <!-- each end -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is loop without element where I can use th:each attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't that be either on the `<tr>` or just simply a `<span>`?

Comment: Yeah, this should definitely be on the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<th:block>` if you don't want to use any html elements.

According to thymeleaf's [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag),

> `th:block` is a mere attribute container that allows template
>   developers to specify whichever attributes they want. Thymeleaf will
>   execute these attributes and then simply make the block dissapear
>   without a trace.
>
> So it could be useful, for example, when creating iterated tables that require more than one  for each element:

for example:

```
<table>
  <th:block th:each="value : ${values}">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
  </tr>
  </th:block>
</table>
```

Comment: you mean `values`